# Splash - Scrapy - HAR data

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash, scrapinghub, splash-js-render

In general I understand how to work with Scrapy and x-path to parse the html. However, I don't know how to grab the HAR data.

```
mport scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/js']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url,
                                callback=self.parse,
                                endpoint='render.html')


    def parse(self, response):
        quotes = response.xpath('//*[@class="quote"]')
        for quote in quotes:
            yield { 'author': quote.xpath('.//*[@class="author"]/text()').extract_first(),
                    'quote': quote.xpath('.//*[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first()
                    }

        script = """function main(splash)
                assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
                splash:wait(0.3)
                button = splash:select("li[class=next] a")
                splash:set_viewport_full()
                splash:wait(0.1)
                button:mouse_click()
                splash:wait(1)
                return {url = splash:url(),
                        html = splash:html(),
                        har = splash:har()}
            end """
        yield SplashRequest(url=response.url,
                                callback=self.parse,
                                endpoint='execute',
                                args={'lua_source':script})
```

What would be the next statement in the script to export the HAR data to a file?  How do I yield all the network data to a file? Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
response.data['har']
```

In you parse method.